# Issues with makemigrations and upgrading to Django 1.7

Tags: django-1.7, makemigrations

My team had a project running on Django 1.6 with South and we just upgraded to 1.7.  I followed the guide, cleared my old South migrations, ran makemigrations and migrate, and ultimately got my server running so I pushed up the changes to our repository.

Now a second developer on my team pulled down from the repo, upgraded to 1.7, and attempted to run migrate (my migrations from makemigrations were in the repo, so there didn't seem to be a need to run makemigrations).  However, he's getting "Models aren't loaded yet" whenever he attempts to migrate (even with --fake).  How can he get his environment up and running without deleting all my migrations and running makemigrations?

Also, looking ahead, we will have to make new schema migrations in 1.7 before pushing the code to our production server which is still on 1.6.  Basically, we'll need to upgrade to 1.7 and then immediately apply new schema changes right after.  Will there be any issues if we move off of South and apply new 1.7 migrations at the same time?  Will Django know the difference between the initial past migrations that South originally applied vs. the new migrations that were created after moving off of South?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up figuring out how to get this to work.

A lot of the "0002" migrations from the initial makemigrations were failing because the tables already existed, so we had to run migrate, fake one of the "0002" migrations, run migrate again, and repeat the process until it went through.  It was a pain but it worked.